# How to add some arrows in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I need to add some arrow to somewhere in Highcharts candlestick diagram like as this image:

[image]

Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: You could do it by adding a scatter series, and using images as the markers (there are examples in the highcharts demo section for using images as markers).  You could use the renderer to draw them yourself, or you could use data labels, the useHTML property, and an icon font...but I would opt for the scatter series personally - more flexibility, control, and existing methods and options

Comment: Thank you @jlbriggs . I will try it.